# No transaction ID returned when the "Skip Receipt Screen" is turned on

Tags: square-connect

I just found that when using the Square Register SDK on iOS, if the "Skip Receipt Screen" setting is turned on at the Square's Point-of-Sale app(ver. 4.62) side, there will be no transaction ID passed back to my app. Is it a bug of Square's Point-of-Sale app?

Comment: So even if you DON'T skip the receipt screen, you still won't get a transaction_id, I just tested that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the client id and then use the REST APIs to pull down the recent transactions and find the one with the matching client id.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't see a `client_id` value anywhere in the list transactions response.
Can you be more specific as to which endpoint we need to use to receive the list of transactions?
Thank you